# How can I track tag badges in my profile?

Tags: support, tag-badges, badge-progress

On Stack Overflow, I would like to track my progress toward the SQL badge on my profile.

I can't figure out how to specify in my Profile → Activity tab → Badges section → Next Badge the 'SQL' tag I wish to track. It seems that I can only track other types of badges.

I think seeing my progress toward a tag badge would encourage me to answer more questions in that tag.

Comment: I was *kinda* poking at this (and having trouble) a few weeks back. Then forgot how I did it  - so not *that* trivial. Else I wouldn't be breaking out the animated gifs ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

Like that, more or less. You need to click on the gear to pick it. Works more or less identically on other sites as well.

Comment: Ah! I was trying to do it in the Badges section (to the right).  Your solution works well.  Thank you.

Comment: Tag badges are a little strange I suppose, especially since the main advantage of a gold tag badge (aside from more badges) is a closehammer for that tag, In an odd way, tag badges are more akin to rep based privileges than other tags are, and having it there almost possibly makes sense.